# Max value for the sum of consecutive indicies (Java)

Tags: java

Write a function int bentley(int a) that return the index, j, from a pair of indices (i,j) such that a[i]+a[i+1]++a[j-1] is maximum over all such pairs (i,j).

^^This is the question i have to answer. Im assuming "a[i]+a[i+1]++a[j-1]"  means from a[i ] to a[j-1]. So far this is what i have:

```
public static int bentley(int[] a) {
int max = 0;
int oldsum = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        sum = oldsum + a[j];
        if (sum > oldsum) {
            max = j;
            oldsum = sum;
        }
        else {
            sum = oldsum;
        }
    }
}
return max;
```

}

It doesnt work, i dont know why or how to fix it.

Comment: 1 - Your question is worded strangely.  I don't know what `a[i]+a[i+1]++a[j-1]` is supposed to represent.  2 - you should at least know the *why* you have to fix it.

Comment: yeah all of the assignment questions are worded like that

Comment: In actuality, the `++` is throwing me off.  Could you clarify at least that?

Comment: just edited it makato

Comment: From the explanation, I believe OP means `a[i] + a[i+1] + ... + a[j-1]`, assuming `i<j` of course.  That is, sum all the numbers from the `i`th one up to the `j-1`th one.